# How to prevent ding sound from Office 365?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

Apps from Office 365 create ding sound on several occasions. I did internet search and unchecked File > Options > Ease of access > Provide feedback with sound box. However, the ding sound continues. Any comments on how to disable this ding completely with Office 365? (Using Windows 10).

Comment: Try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-sound-effects-on-or-off-in-outlook-e37d6cb4-5313-4d60-87fd-c4a7c2e4df59

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel, Sounds, and then select the Sound tab in the window that comes up.

Select None for email notify. This assumes Outlook is your default email handler.

Comment: The problem is not just for incoming emails in Outlook, but all the apps on many different occasions.

Comment: Look through all the app in the sound screen I pointed to for individual app settings.  Make sure you do not have too many apps making sounds. I have lots of apps (many) and no Outlook / Email sounds except for the email notifier settings.